# Apache HTTP Server + PHP install in a specified folder in UNIX

Tags: php, apache, unix, installation, bitnami

I am working on a web application which is written in PHP. I would like to create a packaged installer for the full web application for local installs on to a UNIX box.

- Installer (I can create a shell script to walk through the installation if required)
- Install both PHP and Apapche HTTP server in a given folder rather than /etc /opt etc.

I am not sure if this will be possible or not, however I have seen tomcat server installed in the above config. So if the user want to get rid of the application, just remove the folder and all gone.

Thanks in advance

----- Update ------

Okay I have done some more digging around and found that there is a readily available solution for Windows but not that straight forward for UNIX.

One solution I have found so far is the **xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz** that can be installed only to /opt folder. However the good thing about this is that the installation is in a single folder and more manageable than the normal multi folder installation. The output will become /opt/lampp containing Apache HTTPD web server, PHP, MySQL and PureFTP. This stack of apps seems all suitable to my application so I guess I will need to go with this approach. Details of this can be found here: [link](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/469120-help-to-install-Xampp-for-Linux-(Lampp)-on-a-USB-memory-stick-(under-linux))

Next step I am going to check Bitnami apps, I will try to test it out to see whether there is something similar available with the Bitnami installs.

Please share any info you guys might have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone at the Apache friends (XAMPP) also did something similar, not sure why I did not think about this step.

SO the solution is to unpack the tar.gz package to a folder of choice and than create symbolic link to /opt, just as detailed [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=162965).

Guess this should be good enough for me to accept this solution.